# Why is $(\alpha \times \{0\}) \cup (\beta \times \{1\})$ well-ordered?

Tags: ordinals, well-orders

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be ordinals. Show that $Z:=(\alpha \times \{0\}) \cup (\beta \times \{1\})$ is well-ordered, for the order

$$(\lambda, i) \leq (\mu,j) \iff (i< j) \lor((i=j) \land(\lambda \leq \mu))$$

Well, I guess I will have to show that if $\emptyset \neq Y \subseteq Z$, then $Z$ has a minimum.

How would I construct such a minimum?

I thought maybe to look at the sets

$$Z_\alpha:=\{\gamma \in \alpha: (\gamma,0) \in Y \mathrm{\ or\ } (\gamma,1) \in Y\}$$
$$Z_\beta:=\{\gamma \in \beta: (\gamma,0) \in Y \mathrm{\ or\ } (\gamma,1) \in Y\}$$

At least one of these is non-empty. But then I have to split up multiple cases and this does not seem elegant, so I was hoping there is a simple way to see this is well-ordered.

It is easy to see that $Z$ is total, so we can also show that $Z$ has no strictly decreasing sequence.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't said what the ordering on the union is (although it's fairly easy to guess). As for "multiple cases", there are only two cases to consider!

Comment: Thanks. I edited my post to include the order. Which two cases should I consider then?

Comment: The definition on your sets is not really what you want. I'd suggest looking at the argument in a very simple case: say, $\alpha = \mathbf{2}$ and $\beta=\mathbf{3}$.

Comment: This ordering is really just tacking $\beta$ onto the end of $\alpha$ with the bottom of $\beta$ being greater than all elements of $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the order is just a copy $A = \alpha \times \{0\}$ of $\alpha$ followed by a copy $B = \beta \times \{1\}$ of $\beta$. Given $\emptyset \neq Y \subseteq Z = A \cup B$, there are two cases to consider: (1) $Y \cap A = \emptyset$, and (2) $Y \cap A \neq \emptyset$. In case (2), use the fact that $A$ is well-ordered. In case (1), what can you say about $ Y \cap B$?

Comment: I think I get it. In case (2), we have $Y \cap (A \times 0) \neq \emptyset$, so consider the minimum $\eta:=\{x \in \alpha: (x,0) \in Y\}$ and it is clear that $(\eta, 0)$ is the minimum if $Y$. In case $(1)$, we must have $Y \cap (B \times 1) \neq \emptyset$ and thus we can do the same trick. Does this sound about right?

Comment: That sounds spot on to me.

Comment: Thanks again! Have a great day/night!